# Filtration of Chow variety based on the dimension of the intersection of cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety. Let $Y$ be subvariety of $X$. Consider the Chow variety of $r$ cycles on $X$ denoted by $C_r(X)$ (We can assume it is the Chow of variety of irreducible cycles). Furthermore assume $\text{dim}(Y)> r$ and $\text{Codim}_X(Y)> r$. Consider the following increasing filtration of $C_r(X)$. $F_0$ is space of $r$ cycles that are in $Y$. $F_1$ is the space of cycles that intersect $Y$ at least in a $r-1$ dimensional subvariety and in general $F_i$ is the space of cycles intersecting $Y$ in at least $r-i$ dimensional subvariety. We have the following inclusions:
$$F_0\subset F_1\subset F_2 \subset \ldots \subset F_r=C_r(X)$$

Is it true that each $F_i$ is a closed subvariety of $C_r(X)$?